# Does confidence interval of the mean fully correct for size?

Tags: confidence-interval, sample-size

Say I have heartrate data at every minute during the day.
I suspect the person was exercising at different points during the day (based on some other data), and now I want to examine my hypothesis.
I mark these periods as "Active" and the others as "Inactive", and calculate the mean and confidence interval of the heart rate. They are significantly different.

Now, there are much more "inactive" points than "active". The confidence interval takes this into account by dividing by the square root of `n`, but is this enough?

To make this point a bit clearer, lets say most of the day the heart rate was 60, for 30 minutes it was 100 and for 15 more minutes it was 150. Now, I can mark the 150bpm as either "active" (and join them to the 100bpm), or inactive and join them to the 60 bpm. if I mark them as inactive, I would still arrive at the same conclusion since they would hardly affect the mean and sd.

Reproducible example:

Case 1: I WRONGLY classify the 150bpm as inactive (say I had another source of information which recognized this period as inactive):

```
df <- data_frame(HeartRate = c(rep(60, 300), rep(100, 10), rep(110, 10),
rep(150,10)), IsActive = c(rep(FALSE, 300), rep(TRUE, 10), rep(TRUE, 10), 
rep(FALSE, 10)))
```

And calculate the mean and CI:

```
df %>% group_by(IsActive) %>% summarise(MeanHR = mean(HeartRate), 
low = (-1*qnorm(0.975) * sd(HeartRate)/sqrt(length(HeartRate)))/12, 
high = (qnorm(0.975) * sd(HeartRate)/sqrt(length(HeartRate)))/12)
```

I get:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  IsActive MeanHR    low  high
  <lgl>     <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 FALSE      62.9 -0.148 0.148
2 TRUE      105   -0.187 0.187
```

Case 2: I now classify the 150 bpm as active, and get the same statistical behaviour:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  IsActive MeanHR    low  high
  <lgl>     <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 FALSE        60  0     0    
2 TRUE        120 -0.655 0.655
```

So although I initially classified the 150bpm as inactive, due to the size of the larger group this error gets "swallowed".

Would there be a way to correct for the fact that the 60 bpm appear many times?

Comment: What else is there?

Comment: It seems to me like this is "cheating", because since there are so many points with heart rate equal to ~60, adding 20 points with heartrate = 150 will not have any effect and I can either mark them as "active" or "inactive" and I would not be able to detect a difference in the way I described above.

Comment: I don't understand, why would you mark the 150 values in the same category as the 60 values? The two are clearly different?

Comment: I am just trying to see what would happen if I made a mistake - would this method be able to detect it?

Comment: I don't understand... could you expand your question adding exactly what you want to do and why, what are you trying to show, what conclusions are you asking about, how would adding these values affect mean and sd?

Comment: Your question is unclear. In the sentence *"if I mark them as inactive, I would still arrive at the same conclusion"* what is the conclusion that you refer to? I think what you should aim for is trying to discover the error or variation in the heart-rate measurements. So theoretically you could describe the heart rate as a smoothly varying curve that relates to the 'state' that a person is in (hour of the day, sleeping, eating, state of exercise, etc) *plus* some random variations which may be due to measurement 'errors' as well as due to natural randomness in the signal...

Comment: The conclusion is that the active group has a much higher heartrate than the inactive group, and it the same for both cases although I made a very serious error of misclassifying the high heartrate. This could happen even if I made a lot of misclassification errors, since the 60 bpm group is so much larger - I can practically "afford" to miss all of the active period

Comment: .... you can discover this variation by plotting a suitable smoothing function to the data and observe the residuals. Based on those residuals you can make arguments like having a certain confidence that the change in the mean of heart-rate over a certain period relates to a a certain change in trend or not.

Comment: What *is* the 'active group' and the 'inactive group'?

Comment: Physically active (running, exercising...)

Comment: Be more specific. What is the *meaning* of 'group'? what did you do? What do you try to quantify? *How* did you perform the experiment.

Comment: I am trying to use the heartrate data to learn whether the person was physically active at the time. In addition, I have steps data, and I am assuming that if someone made a lot of steps for a period of time i can classify him as active. But as I showed above, it doesn't have to correlate with the heartrate data, because of the fact that during the day we mainly have the resting heartrate

Comment: Can you give more details. This is just a broad description and not clear at all. also, 'learn' what does that mean? a short stepwise and concrete description of the experiment will help a lot, in order to understand what you mean.

Comment: What do you mean by 'as I showed above'? You haven't mentioned steps and correlation before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83666/discussion-between-omry-atia-and-martijn-weterings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used your data files

```
transfer.sh/xuf6M/HR.csv
transfer.sh/kW6lb/Steps.csv
```

and in order to match the different time stamps I took averages over 3 minute intervals.

---

This can be turned into the following graphs:

[image: example plots]

You could say then:

- **No activity:** HR of 80 or lower only occur below 5 steps per minute
- **Low activity:** HR of 80-100 do not occur much in activities with above 20 steps per minute
- **Medium activity:** HR of 100-140 occur in activities with above 20 steps per minute
- **High activity or anomalies:** HR above 140 seem to not occur in activities with above 20 steps. These might be other activities than walking that are harder than walking (e.g. running, cycling)

So in this way you calibrate heart rates according to stepsizes. And **you should not consider the heart rates above > 150 as inactive just because you did not measure steps during that period.** Logically you should have 
$$HR_{\text{no activity}} < HR_{\text{low activity}} < HR_{\text{medium activity}} < HR_{\text{high activity}}$$

---

In your case using confidence intervals seems not right to me. You could *mathematically* express something like the average heart rate for a certain activity and express something like a confidence interval for it, but the question is whether it makes sense (aside from your question about the proper categorization of activity and it's influence on the confidence intervals). (1) The heart rates do not follow an ordinary distribution for which you can express the confidence intervals of the mean/average (e.g. using a t-distribution for the mean when the data is Gaussian distributed) (2) The average/mean heart rate may not be the relevant parameter.

---

Possibly plots like below may help you as well:

[image: multiple days]

Here the points are connected and the lines are a path in time (succeeding points in time are connected). So you can see that the high >140 heart-rates are due to the day 1 and day 2. You can also see that these points are in a loop with some walking or running, so it seems that there has been some mixture of walking and other activities.